# Need help figuring out how to save my BOOL inside my button

Tags: ios, uiimage, boolean

I placed a BOOL inside a UIButton. If I click on the Button once, then I want that BOOL to always be saved so I never has to click on button again while in the game. I used the following code but it doesn't work to save. However, the code should work. It's mainly the final line of code that makes the saving not work. What am I doing wrong?

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:REDguy forKey:@"save"];

if (REDguy==[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize]) {
MAN.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"RED.png"];
}

REDguy=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]boolForKey:@"save"];
}
```

EDIT:

```
if (REDguy==YES) {
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:REDguy forKey:@"save"]; 
    REDguy =[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]boolForKey:@"save"];
     MAN.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"RED.png"];
}
```

Comment: Why are you comparing `REDguy` against the result of calling `synchronize`? That doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

This is an assumption since you didn't really clarify what else is going on in your code, but it looks like your bool `REDGuy` is always going to be be `NO` on viewDidLoad, and that `if` condition is likely to always be false since `synchronize` will probably always be `YES` (not to mention, that comparison makes no sense and it's rarely necessary to call `synchronize` since synchronization with user defaults happens on its own).

A simple way to determine if a button has been pressed before is to add the following to your button action method.

```
- (void)buttonAction:(id)sender {
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"save"];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    BOOL hasSaved = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"save"];
    if (hasSaved) {
        // You can hide your button here if that's what you're going for
        [yourButton setHidden:YES]
    }
}
```

Is that what you are trying to accomplish? Determining if a specific button has been tapped before?

Comment: I edited my code above, it works but does it make sense? Yes, that's what i'm trying to do, determine if a specific button has been tapped once.

Comment: No, that does not make any sense. You're setting the key-value "save" in NSUserDefaults, and then just getting that same value back, the one you just set in the previous line of code. You need to set the "save" key-value when the button is pressed (in the button action method). Then, your `if` condition should check against the "save" value in NSUserDefaults. You likely do not need the REDGuy property. Have you tried implementing the solution I posted?

Comment: I have tried placing the setBool line of code in the official REDGuy button that I have. While posting boolForKey in viewDidLoad where I have the choosing of characters selection. It didn't work. Believe me i've been testing different ways of using NSUserDefaults code for several days. No combination of trial and error worked until the 2 that I posted above. I found it unusual myself, but it works.